# async js validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, async-await

Good morning ! 
Currently I am trying to create some kind of simple validation using javascript, but I have a problem with using async functionalities.

Below you can see UI method which iterates through validityChecks collections

```
    checkValidity: function(input){
        for(let i = 0; i<this.validityChecks.length; i++){

            var isInvalid = this.validityChecks[i].isInvalid(input);//promise is returned
            if(isInvalid){
                this.addInvalidity(this.validityChecks[i].invalidityMessage);
            }

            var requirementElement = this.validityChecks[i].element;
            if(requirementElement){
                if(isInvalid){
                    requirementElement.classList.add('invalid');
                    requirementElement.classList.remove('valid');
                }else{
                    requirementElement.classList.remove('invalid');
                    requirementElement.classList.add('valid');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is specific collection object which is not working as it was intended

```
var usernameValidityChecks = [
    {
        isInvalid: function(input){
            var unwantedSigns = input.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g);
            return unwantedSigns ? true:false;
        },
        invalidityMessage:'Only letters and numbers are allowed',
        element: document.querySelector('.username-registration li:nth-child(2)')
    },
    {
        isInvalid: async function (input){
            return await checkUsername(input.value);
        },
        invalidityMessage: 'This value needs to be unique',
        element: document.querySelector('.username-registration li:nth-child(3)')
    }

]
```

```
function checkUsername (username) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>{
        $.ajax({
            url: "check.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { user_name: username },
            success: (data, statusText, jqXHR) => {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                reject(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that to var isInvalid in checkValidity method is returned promise. Can anyone advice how to returned there value instead of promise ? Or how to handle promise there ? 
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT :**
Forgive me, but it is my first time with Stack and probably my question is a little bit inaccurate. Some of objects in collections are also **synchronous**, I changed **usernameValidityChecks**. How to handle this kind of situation ? 
Where I have async and sync method at the same time ?

Comment: Since all the methods are async, do you need to check all the validations even if one failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of below line

> var isInvalid = this.validityChecks[i].isInvalid(input);

you can use below code to make code much cleaner and store the desired value on the variable however above suggested solutions are also correct

> var isInvalid = await this.validityChecks[i].isInvalid(input).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });

After this line you will get the desired value on **isInvalid** variable

And also add **async** keyword in all other **isInvalid** function definition

Comment: You mean **isInvalid** function?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax error,as the function is not async so await wil throw this error

Comment: My suggested solution will work for the resolved promise however for rejected promise we need to add a catch block. Let me update my solution

Comment: await needs async function to work ,await will work only in async function -have a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#See_also

Comment: Yes I agreed but if  you see in the array **usernameValidityChecks** , isInvalid function is having **async** on it and we must add async keyword in all other isInvalid function

Comment: So your final recommendation is to add async to all functions in **usernameValidityChecks** even if they are not being truly asynchronous ?

Comment: Yes specially those function which are returning promise and in my point of view  all the **isInvalid** function should have same function declaration for better code structure

Comment: @ŁukaszNaróg If you find my answer helpful then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Use `.then` to access the result of a promise:

```
var isInvalid = this.validityChecks[i].isInvalid(input).then(res => res);
```